# jQuery: Hiding 'active class' when mouse not over

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have the following jQuery plugin: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slide-out-and-drawer-effect/

Now the problem is: I would like to close the active 'drawer' when the mouse is not over the element. The jQuery is set to keep the active one open until the mouseover is applied to another drawer element. How do I close all the drawers when not hovering over any of them?

Initialization code:

```
$(function () {
    $('UL.drawers').accordion({
        // the drawer handle
        header: 'H2.drawer-handle',

        // our selected class
        selectedClass: 'open',

        // match the Apple slide out effect
        event: 'mouseover'
    });
});
```

Also, when I apply the 'open' class to the drawer element css (`.drawer-handle.open {}`), the active drawer-handle does not change color(animate) as it should. Why is that? I'm using PHP within Joomla 1.7

Thanks!

Comment: @Emmanuel: Why would you _introduce_ errors in an edit?

Comment: You can hide the drawers on mouseout of the div that wraps the whole menu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Shawn. Do I close the parent/containing Div element within the jquery <script></script> tags? and how do I call that function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution for you:

```
$(function() {
    var $accordian = $('UL.drawers').accordion({
        // the drawer handle
        header: 'H2.drawer-handle',

        // our selected class
        selectedClass: 'open',

        // match the Apple slide out effect
        event: 'mouseover',

        // allow all drawers to be closed (default is "true" - always keep a draw open)
        alwaysOpen: false
    }).activate(false);

    $('UL.drawers').mouseout(function () {
        // close all the drawers when the mouse leaves the parent list
        $accordian.activate(false);
    });
});
```

I say partial because the behavior of this setup is not quite as smooth as I think it should be, but if the result is close to what you are looking for it should get you started in the right direction.

You can see it in action with this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gKNGh/1/

Comment: I have one big prob however. My classes and code is exactly like in the example, but the 'open' class is not being applied to my currently opened drawer. How can I fix that? Alternate code/method?

Comment: @DextrousDave You mentioned that you were having trouble styling it with `.drawer-handle.open` but the sample code I used to make the jsFiddle does exactly that and works without issue. Are you sure that you do not have another selector that would be overriding the style on those headers? I would be surprised if the `open` class was never applied, but it is being added dynamically so you would need to use something like Chrome's "Inspect Element" to see it. It will not simply show up when you "View Source"